# can't open file 'manager.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create an application using python and django, but this error keeps happening. [image: my screen]

What I've already tried:

- put python path and script in environment variables
- reinstall python
- reinstall django
- close and open vscode (I thought it was an update issue)
- run the server inside setup - the application folder

If anyone can help me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run the right command which is:

```
python manage.py runserver
```